# QItemDelegate own custom Calendar item drawing

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtableview, qitemdelegate

Im working on a project where i would like to create a custom Calendar in pyqt. I have a custom model and a custom QTableView with surrounding QDateTime processing functions.
In the paint function from QItemDelegate there is no way to draw a Item which goes over multiple rows in the table view.
I dont know how to implement this like its implemented in MS Teams.

Currently ive got a solution where i save one calender item per cell with the same information. In the paint
event i ask the item if its the first item and draw the background relative to the cell size.

[image: 1]

Is it performant to let the QTableView paintEvent draw its items itself over the cells?

[image: I want this]

Comment: A delegate is not strictly forbidden to draw beyond its own cell, the problem is that the view's implementation (and its style) may not properly update "related cells" when the original one is changed or when mouse events occur (such as hovering), because a view only repaints cells that actually need updates for optimization reasons. It's still possible to work around that (by checking mouse movements and data changes), but it needs to be done appropriately, to avoid drawing artifacts or missing cells

Comment: Thx musicanmante. Do you have an idea how i could do it like MS does it with MS Teams in the second picture? Maybe like u said, an own update mechanism?